# mongoid get embedded documents parent by childrens id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, embedded-documents

I have two models

```
Class FirstModel
  embeds_one :second_model, class_name: 'V1::SecondModel'

Class SecondModel
  embedded_in :first_model, class_name 'V1::FirstModel'
```

I have some records of first model and I can get second model records from first models object in my rails c console as
    firstmodelobj.second_model

I have googled and tried enough but I can't seem to find the first model(parent) object from the second model(child) object's id.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it,

```
V1::FirstModel.where("second_model._id" => Moped::BSON::ObjectId("id")).first
```